# C++ boost async_accept exception "already open"

Tags: c++, sockets, boost

I'm having a little problem that I cannot see a lot of people have come into with boost async_accept.

This is how I'm handling the async_accept and how I call it.

```
void Server::accept()
{
    try {
        Connection* connection = new Connection(io_service);
        connections.push_back(connection);
        acceptor->async_accept(connection->getSocket(), std::bind(&Server::onAccept, this, std::placeholders::_1, connection));
    }
    catch (const boost::system::system_error& e) {
        std::cout << "> [Error - Server::start]: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

void Server::onAccept(const boost::system::error_code& e, Connection* connection)
{
    if (e) {
        std::cout << "> [Error - Server::onAccept]: " << e.message() << std::endl;
        connection->disconnect();
        return;
    }

    connection->read();
    accept();
}
```

The method *connection->getSocket()* returns a reference to the *boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket* variable from the connection class.
The connection is accepted, but when onAccept is called, there is a "Already open" error which I cannot seem to find the solution to.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the code shown.

Google [shows many people having the same issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hteEs.png), and one of the top 3 hits shows it being caused by the fact that the client connection class is being used, while this is a server.

Client connections **initiate** the connection, so if you copy/pasted that code, you would have an open connection, which is of course "Already open".

Check that you didn't open the socket in the `Connection` class. Alternatively, check that you're instantiating the correct type in `new Connection` (name and namespace).